# Mini displayport to displayport cable?

Tags: displayport, mini-displayport

I have a MacBook pro with a mini-display port, I have a Dell 2709W display with a DisplayPort (not mini). I cannot for the life of me find a cable or adapter for sale in the UK that will let me plug a mini-display port into a display port.

Ideally I'd be after a cable that just has a mini plug on one end, and a full size plug on the other.

I've seen lots of Mini-displayport to HDMI adapters around, but I don't want one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a place in the UK selling these, finally, Alex's tip led me to find it.

[Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort Adapter Cable: Lindy UK](http://www.lindy.co.uk/mini-displayport-to-displayport-adapter-cable/41022.html)

I'll award this best answer as it answers the question, but give an up-vote to Alex, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can find some [here](http://estore.circuitassembly.com/products/Mini-Displayport-to-Displayport-Adapter-Cable.html) for 15$ + about 12$ for shipping to the UK. Here's what the first reviewer says:

> Works like a charm with 17" MBP mid 2009 and Dell 2709W - nothing more to add